# Laravel queue not working and not show the error

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I want to create customer's folders in `/public/storage` based on `customer id` from database (due to server corrupt). I tried using Laravel queue.

Here is my code. This is to only create folder. When I run `php artisan queue:work` or `listen`, nothing happens on my terminal.

The scenario is: system will create a folder name based on `customer id` and save the folder into `laravel/public/storage/uploads/file/folder`

```php
<?php
  
namespace App\Jobs;
   
use App\Model\Document;
use App\Model\Term;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class Restore implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
  
    protected $folder;
     
    public function __construct($folder)
    {
        $this->queue = 'default'; //choose a queue name
        $this->connection = 'database';
        $this->folder = $folder;
    }
   
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);

            $makedir = Term::get();
            foreach ($makedir as $mkdir) {
                $path = public_path().'/storage/uploads/file/'.$mkdir->id_praapplication;
                $file_user = Document::get();

                if(!(file_exists($path))) {
                    $folder = File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
                    dispatch(new Restore($folder));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually dispatching the job? After dispatching you should see it being handled in your terminal where the queue worker is running.

Comment: yes i run php artisan queue:work/listen in the terminal. but showing nothing

Comment: That command is listen for new jobs, and if a new job beginners present it will process it. But that means you first need to dispatch a job to the queue, add described here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-jobs